# Nested ngFor pass value inner to outer

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have nested ngFor and I am trying to pass value from inner ngFor to outer ngFor. is that possible.

```
  <div *ngFor="let links of links$?.links, let i = index" class="circleBtns {{links.id}}" (click)="clickButton({{linkHref.url}})">
      <div *ngFor="let linkHref of links.box">
          <div *ngIf="linkHref.group.indexOf(pageId) > -1" >
              <div>{{linkHref.url}}</div> //send this linkHref.url to clickButton function above        
         </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

I would prefer not to run second ngFor if that can be directly access from first.

Answer (score 1):

Try by using the following code, you can't used like you want it, but I don't know if it will work but you can try this code, an advice is try to change your JSON array model to have a better access to the variables.

```
      <div *ngFor="let links of links$?.links, let i = index" 
            class="circleBtns {{links.id}}" 
           (click)="clickButton({{links.box.filter(x => x.group.indexOf(pageId) > -1)[0].url}})"
```

>

Comment: Lol, nice I haven't did before  :)